# How to know a mysql variable is a system or user defined var in mysql command client?

Tags: mysql

I open mysql client, and type this:

> show variables like 'var'

it just told me that this is a variable, but it didn't say anything about the properties of this variable.

maybe there are another mysql commands/syntaxs to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SELECT @var;**   works for user variable

**SELECT @@var;**   works for system variables

eg:

SELECT @var1;

SELECT @@sql_mode;

If you use @@var with user defined variables, you will get an error.